# How to get modal data on modal dismiss in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a Page with a List. From that page I open a MODAL.
That modal contains a Text box and a Add Item Button.
When I enter an Item in the Box and Hit Add Item, I need to
1) Dismiss the Modal
2) Add the entered Item in the List in the Previous List

I need to do this via On Dismiss().

HOME.HTML

```
    <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let grocery of itemsArray">{{grocery}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button round (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</ion-content>
```

HOME.TS

```
    export class HomePage {

  public itemsArray = [];
  newItem: String;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.newItem = this.navParams.get('data');
    this.itemsArray = [
      'Bread',
      'Milk',
      'Cheese',
      'Snacks',
      'Apples',
      'Bananas',
      'Peanut Butter',
      'Chocolate',
      'Avocada',
      'Vegemite',
      'Muffins',
      'Paper towels'
    ];
    this.itemsArray.push(this.newItem)

  }
  public addItem() {
    let modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    modalPage.onDidDismiss(data => {
      this.newItem = data;
    });
    modalPage.present();
  }
}
```

MODAL.HTML

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Add Item</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Item</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="add()">Add Item</button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

MODAL.TS

```
    export class ModalPage {
  name:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalPage');
  }
  public closeModal() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();

  }
  add() {
    let data = {"name": this.name};
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data)
  }

}
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried. The page that calls the modal and the modal page itself.

Comment: @SimãoGarcia Sorry for not providing proper code. I have edited it now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good stuff @Shylesh. Hope your problem is solved.

Comment: @SimãoGarcia No. Im still not getting the data in the list! can you help with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine overall.

Change this part.

```
public addItem() {
    let modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    modalPage.onDidDismiss(data => {
      this.itemsArray.push(data);
    });
    modalPage.present();
  }
```

Change the name of your variable on the html or the TS file. 
`name` to `newItem` or vice-versa

You are using `[(ngModel)]="newItem"` but in your TS file your using `this.name`

You're adding the item on `ionViewDidLoad()` but the new item arrives at `modalPage.onDidDismiss()`

Give it a try. I'll help you further if it still does not work.

Comment: Try it and give some feedback. If you want other people to help you out, you have to unmark the other answer as accepted. People will think your problem is solved.

Comment: This worked. 
had to imply this in the code to add the item to list

this.itemsArray.push(data.name);

Answer (score 1):

First you need to pass object/string of item/data from you mode while you are closing the same

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
```

And you have to subscribe model closing event at the page from where you have opened it for ex.

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModelPage);
modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    this.badge = data;
});
modal.present();
```

After you can simply push you new item in to items array :)

Comment: Cant get it still.. I have edited the code and uploaded.. can you check whats wrong??